# Is it possible to do liquid animations in Flutter?

Tags: animation, flutter

Just wondering if can we do such cool liquid animations in Flutter

https://dribbble.com/shots/9089080-Organic-notification-for-Natural-AI

Comment: That's not an easy task :v so much complex. Try with Adobe animate or after effects package

Answer (score 1):

You can try Rive (https://rive.app/explore/popular/trending/all) by using flare. Checkout Flutter Interact 2019 for Rive